# Is there a way to use PySpark with Hadoop 2.8+?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I would like to run a PySpark job locally, using a specific version of Hadoop (let's say hadoop-aws 2.8.5) because of some features.

PySpark versions seem to be aligned with Spark versions.

Here I use PySpark 2.4.5 which seems to wrap a Spark 2.4.5.

When submitting my PySpark Job, using `spark-submit --local[4] ...`, with the option `--conf spark.jars.packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5`, I encounter the following error:

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.sql`

With the following java exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
```

Or:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init (Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation
```

I suppose that the Pyspark Job Hadoop version is unaligned with the one I pass to the `spark-submit` option `spark.jars.packages`.

But I have not any idea of how I could make it work? :)

Comment: Is the hadoop cluster also local? If it is, great. If not, the the philosophy is "bring the computation to the data" and not "bring the data to the computation"

Comment: @Z4-tier: Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution:

1 - Install Hadoop in the expected version (2.8.5 for me)

2 - Install a Hadoop Free version of Spark (2.4.4 for me)

3 - Set `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` environment variable, to make Spark uses the custom version of Hadoop.

(cf. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/hadoop-provided.html)

4 - Add the PySpark directories to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, like the following:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```

(Note that the py4j version my differs)

That's it.

Comment: i am also looking for this solution. I just need hadoop libraries for spark without any hdfs. I wanted with specific versios of spark and hadoop and java and finally aws s3

Answer (score 0):

Default spark disto has hadoop libraries included. Spark use system (its own) libraries first. So you should either set `--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` and for cluster add `--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true` or download spark distro without hadoop. Probably you will have to put your hadoop distro  into spark disto jars directory.